# How to add conditional checks over ORM (sequelizejs) queries?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

Suppose i have a table **gameData {gameId, currentBoardLayout}**, a get request like www.chess.com/**asd123** is sent over to the server, where asd123 is my game id, I need to catch this id (asd123 which is my gameId) and check for it in my table (gameData) and implement the following logic :

```js
srv.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if ( gameData.findAll({where: {gameId: req.params.id} )
            { // Game room found
                return currentBoardLayout
            }
    else
            { error : Invalid game id }
    })
```

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sequelize's `findById` method.

```
srv.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  gameData.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(result => {
      res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.send({
        error: 'Could not find ID'
      })
    })
})
```

Here's what is happening:

1. Sequelize's `findById` method will return a promise. If it successful, you will get your item from the database back. If the item cannot be found, the `catch` method will fire.
2. `res.send` is Express' way of sending data back to the client.

It is worth checking out the Sequelize docs:

- [Using models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)
- [Querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)